# Explanation of sed regular expression

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I am doing an assignment for university related to writing scripts in Bash.

Part of my assignment includes using `tar` to archive some files from a specific folder. I also needed the resulting tarball to not include the folder structure. Just the archived files.

After some Googling I finally found something that worked for me.

```
tar xvf some.tar --transform 's?.*/??g'
```

This did the job nicely. But I can't really figure out what exactly the sed expression `'s?.*/??g'` does in the code. I tried searching but couldn't find anything useful.

Can somebody explain what that regex does? I really want to understand it.

Comment: That transformation is being done on *extraction*. The tarball itself still contains the full paths. So that doesn't exactly satisfy the requirement you said you had. Just FYI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regex just looks extra complicated because they are using `?` as the separator. A rather odd choice. If you were to use a more familiar separator, like `|`, it looks a bit nicer `'s|.*/||g'`

`s` - do a search and replace

`g` - globally (replace all instances found)

`.*/` - matches any sets of characters followed by a slash

`||` - empty (replace with nothing)

Looks like it is removing the file path from the output name.

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what it does.